# CSS - What order does sizing go in css:

Tags: html, css, frontend, margin

What order would this go in?

```
div{
    margin:0px 0px 13px 0px;
}
```

What side of the div would the 13px effect?

Also would I need all of the px or just one or none?

could I do this?

```
div{
    margin:0 0 13 0;
}
```

Comment: I would suggest you to read basic notes on margin in CSS here - https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_margin.asp

Answer (score 1):

It goes in this order: top, right, bottom and left. For example:

```
div {
  margin: 1px 2px 3px 4px;
}
```

is equal to

```
div {
  margin-top: 1px;
  margin-right: 2px;
  margin-bottom: 3px;
  margin-left: 4px;
}
```

You also can specify only 2 properties, and for example:

```
div {
  margin: 10px 20px;
}
```

means the following: `margin-top` and `margin-bottom` are equal to `10px`, `margin-left` and `margin-right` are equal to `20px`.

You can also specify 3 values, like this:

```
div {
  margin: 1px 2px 3px;
}
```

And it equals to:

```
div {
  margin-top: 1px;
  margin-right: 2px;
  margin-bottom: 3px;
  margin-left: 2px;
}
```

And as you already know `margin: 1px` will set all 4 margins to `1px`.

When you specifuing a number not equal to 0, you should specify `px` or `%` and so on, but when you specify `0`, it can be just `0`, it's OK.

Comment: you may also add the case where we can specify 1 value and 3 values :)

Comment: @TemaniAfif, thanks! I think, that you answer is structured better than mine and has a comprehensive information, so I'm upvoting you too, Sir ;)